# Date matching in BASH doesn't return the correct value

Tags: bash, sorting, date, formatting

I have a bunch of scripts running where I am supposed to match filename to a date, for instance, xxxx_xxxx_20240214_xxxx.txt

I use $(date +%Y%m%d)*.txt to get the date in the file, and the script can't find it. But when I run something like
ls -all /home/???/ | grep "xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_$(date +%Y%m%d)*.txt" I get the following matches:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1363459 Feb 14 01:10 xxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxx_**2024021**0.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1373367 Feb 14 01:10 xxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxx_**2024021**1.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1385752 Feb 14 01:10 xxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxx_**2024021**2.txt
```

It seems the year is being picked up ok, the month is too, but the day consists of only the first character. If I change the date variables to %Y%m only, it gets kinda strange, instead of picking up only 02 - Feb, it also picks up the 0 from January's 01... any ideas? I am lost here... I am not a bash coding guy, so I am running blind here... thanks guys

I tried different combinations of date variables, all to no effect...

This is the basic output of ls:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLP1d.jpg)

I need to pick up yesterday's file with [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vNK9.jpg)

However, it picks up yesterday's and today's file

In the following output, I am expecting to see only the today's file "xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_20240215_0217_txt" yet, I see more than that:

```
ls -all /home/X/ | grep "xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_$(date --date="today" +"%Y%m%d")*"
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  884314 Feb 10 02:20 xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_20240210_0217_txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  908165 Feb 11 10:40 xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_20240211_0217_txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  882120 Feb 12 02:20 xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_20240212_0217_txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  772674 Feb 13 02:20 xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_20240213_0217_txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  725187 Feb 14 02:20 xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_20240214_0217_txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  789609 Feb 15 19:10 xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_20240215_0217_txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In regular expression, `*` means **zero** or more preceding characters. Just `grep` the characters you want to grep. You could disable regular expression with `grep -F`.

```
ls -al /home/X/ | grep "xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_$(date --date="today" +"%Y%m%d")"
```

But do not parse ls. Consider using glob:

```
ls -al /home/X/xxxx_xxxxx_xxxx_$(date --date="today" +"%Y%m%d")*
```

Consider researching: what is regular expression `man 7 regex`, what is glob expression `man 7 glob`, and how do they differ, see grep documentation `man grep`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead .

Comment: Thank you very much! This was what I was missing! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure proper date formatting and use reliable commands like "date" in BASH. Validate date formats, use quotes to prevent word splitting, and consider timezone issues. Debug with "echo" commands to track variables. If issues persist, share code snippets for more specific assistance in troubleshooting date matching problems.